# What were the commitment action items?

Tags: support

When this community did not exist there was a [commitment](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/106955/quantum-computing) phase.

Where can I find now the list of action items from the commitment statement? How do I know how much is left for me to fulfill the commitment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People who committed to this proposal can fulfill their commitment by asking or answering 10 questions within the beta period. Once you've fulfilled the commitment, be warned it does take a little time to update.

See also [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90886/336074) (source of commitment requirements) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63973/when-is-a-commitment-fulfilled-on-area-51) (explanation of updating) mother meta questions. You can see the commitment phase page [here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/106955?phase=commitment).

Comment: Hello, does meta participiation count too?

Comment: @MEE I don't think so.

Comment: Does the rule of 10 questions/answers apply to commitments for all proposals? I can't find the proof.

Comment: @AlexanderPozdneev yes, it applies to commitments for all proposals. The "See also this", where "this" is a link, is an example of some proof for this.

Comment: @AlexanderPozdneev - This [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/305480/282094) offers an explanation. I fulfilled my commitment (according to my A51 user profile) and scored 50 Rep simply by referring two users; so it seems other methods than listed in that answer also work.